# SELECT count() inside AFTER INSERT trigger incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an AFTER INSERT-trigger that looks like this.

```
BEGIN
    SET @newcompany = NEW.company_id; 
    IF NEW.company_id is not null THEN

        SET @my_result = (SELECT count(*) FROM wp_wysija_user u
            LEFT JOIN wp_pods_company c ON c.id = u.company_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_podsrel rel ON c.id = rel.item_id
            WHERE rel.field_id=3384 AND rel.related_item_id=5 AND u.company_id = @newcompany);

        INSERT INTO wp_wysija_user_list(list_id, user_id, sub_date)
        VALUES (5, NEW.user_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

        IF @my_result > 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO wp_wysija_user_list(list_id, user_id, sub_date)
            VALUES (7, NEW.user_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
        END IF;     
    END IF;
END
```

My problem is that @my_result is always 0. If I run the query outside the trigger I get the right count. At first I thought that the variable @newcompany didn´t get a value. But I have checked that.

I need help here!

Comment: are you sure your trigger gets executed?

Comment: The left joins that you used here is the same as inner join.

Comment: Yes the trigger executes because the first INSERT is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you use LEFT joins????

```
    BEGIN
SET @newcompany = NEW.company_id; 
IF NEW.company_id is not null THEN

    SET @my_result = (SELECT count(*) FROM wp_wysija_user u
        LEFT JOIN wp_pods_company c ON c.id = u.company_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_podsrel rel ON c.id = rel.item_id and rel.field_id=3384 AND        
                                                           rel.related_item_id=5
        WHERE  u.company_id = @newcompany);

    INSERT INTO wp_wysija_user_list(list_id, user_id, sub_date)
    VALUES (5, NEW.user_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

    IF @my_result > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO wp_wysija_user_list(list_id, user_id, sub_date)
        VALUES (7, NEW.user_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
    END IF;     
END IF;
```

END

Comment: I guess you think I should INNER JOIN?

Comment: I modified your query pasted above. Try it and see if works. Your left joins are treated the same as inner join anyway in your code.

Comment: Hi, just back to work and run your modified query and it worked. Thank you so much. I have never used AND-condition at the join before. Great!